# How to login with Google Oauth with google customised email only

Tags: plugins, google-api

I want to create a Sign In With Google function on a client's project but I want the users to log in with google's customized email addresses instead of the normal @gmail.com. I am trying to follow the tutorial here http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/login-with-google-account-oauth.html  but the link has nothing on my question. Please kindly help.